# JavaScript cannot read property 'style' of undefined when using parentElement.nextSiblingElement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dropdown filter. So when the dropdown-arrow beside the filter heading is clicked, the list should disappear and when it is clicked again the list should reappear. The problem is, since the dropdown list is located in the sibling element of the parent element of the dropdown-arrow, I am trying to navigate my JavaScript function by using **parentElement.nextSiblingElement** and change the display but it throws an error **'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined'**.

```js
dropdown = (target) => {
  target.parentElement.nextSiblingElement.style.display == 'block' ? target.parentElement.nextSiblingElement.style.display = 'none' : target.parentElement.nextSiblingElement.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.brand-head {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.brand-head p {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.brand-head i {
  padding: 15px 20px 5px;
}

.brand-options .option {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding: 2px 0;
  display: flex;
}

.brand-options .option-check {
  width: 15px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(194, 194, 194);
  height: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: background-color 200ms;
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

.brand-options p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/pro.min.css">
<div class="brand-filter">
  <div class="brand-head">
    <p>BRAND</p>
    <i class="fas fa-angle-down" onclick="dropdown(event.target)"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="brand-options">
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-check"></div>
      <p>Philips</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-check"></div>
      <p>Bajaj</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-check"></div>
      <p>Prestige</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-check"></div>
      <p>Bosch</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-check"></div>
      <p>Usha</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
      <div class="option-check"></div>
      <p>Samsung</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) instead of `nextSiblingElement`?

Comment: Beacsue `target.parentElement.nextSiblingElement` is undefined

Comment: It means that `target.parentElement.nextSiblingElement` is undefined. There is no nextSiblingElement on the parent element.

Comment: @Ivar It seems I wrote an incorrect syntax. I changed it from nextSiblingElement to nextElementSibling and it worked.